# shopify: what does filter "t" do?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app

```
{{general.newsletter_form.placeholder' | t }}
```

I find something like this in a shopify's .liquid file, I am trying to find out what `t` means but can't find any related information from shopify's help center and liquid's github page. Can anyone tell me what it does and more importantly, where I can find the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the front-end translation filter or an attempt to bring i18n to Shop themes. See the documentation here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/internationalizing/translation-filter